# How to retrieve data from all options if user selects `All`

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Got a mysqli/php code below where it will display results depending on option selected from the `question` drop down menu:

```
$selectedquestionqry = "
SELECT
QuestionNo
FROM
Question
WHERE
(QuestionId = ?)
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedquestionstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedquestionqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$selectedquestionstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["question"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedquestionstmt->execute(); 
$selectedquestionstmt->bind_result($selQuestionNo);
$selectedquestionstmt->store_result();
$selquestionnum = $selectedquestionstmt->num_rows();   


 while ($selectedquestionstmt->fetch()) {

if($_POST["question"] === '0') {
    echo "<p>All Questions - Total:(" . $selquestionnum . ")</p>" . PHP_EOL;
}else if($_POST["question"] !== '0') {
echo "<p><strong>Questions: </strong>" . $selQuestionNo . "</p>" . PHP_EOL;
}
}
```

DROP DOWN MENU:

```
 <select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="23">Jay Hart</option>
    <option value="32">Bubba Wright</option>
    </select>
```

My question is that how can I get it so that if the user has selected '0', then it will be able to select all questions from the db which are displayed in the `question` drop down menu?

The reason I am asking this is because in my echo `else if($_POST["question"] !== '0') {
echo "<p><strong>Questions: </strong>" . $selQuestionNo . "</p>" . PHP_EOL;
}`, nothing is being echo when I select the `All` option, which to me makes me think that it is not displaying the echo due to this. If I select a single question from drop down menu, it is able to output it's echo.

Comment: work on your query with these conditions, when question === 0 the remove where clause in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to modify your query:

```
if($_POST["question"] === '0') {
    $selectedquestionqry = "SELECT QuestionNo FROM Question";
} else {
    $selectedquestionqry = "SELECT QuestionNo FROM Question WHERE (QuestionId = ?)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query to remove the `WHERE` condition based the posted value being  `'0'`.  You shouldn't have to change any of your code after that since you're already looping, but you should display the Total outside of the loop.